# Did I convince the camper to move in?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Today I got a camper, Cookie. Since I only have 9 in my down, I could ask her to move in. The first time I asked her she said "Great! I was hoping you'd say that. You'll have to convince everyone that Cookie will be cool in Liverpol (My town in the game)" So I don't know if she accepted or rejected.

She's not asking to move in again and keeps saying "Its REALLY important that I get along with my neighbours. I mean, we're all in this together, right? That means I'll have to do a little snooping around and check out what kinds of folk live here!"

I think I convinced her to move in but I just want to double check. Have I convinced her to move in? And if I have, when will she move in?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, have you talked to any other villagers in your town afterwards?

Comment: No but I know I did because I went on my friends account and got them to visit Cookie and she told them "The Mayor totally convinced me to move in so I am!"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did convince her to move in. What I think she meant when she said that you have to convince your other villagers that she would be cool in your town was so that she would have a good reputation when she moved in.